# Inno Setup - npm program added to PATH by subinstaller is not recognized in a batch file executed from installer

Tags: node.js, batch-file, npm, inno-setup

I have created a Windows installer using Inno Setup for an app I have made. As part of the installer I have included the installation of some third party applications followed by a batch file, to execute a number of `npm` command operable program or batch file.

Everything installs okay but when the batch file runs I get the message

> 'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command

The commands don't run and so the app won't open.  However, if I leave everything as it is and just rerun the batch file again after the installation, the commands execute and the app works fine.  How can I get the batch file to run properly as part of the installation?

**Inno Setup `Run` Section**

```
[Run]
Filename: "{tmp}\Git-2.15.0-64-bit.exe";  Flags: waituntilterminated
Filename: "{tmp}\rubyinstaller-2.3.3-x64.exe";  Flags: waituntilterminated
Filename: "{tmp}\visualcppbuildtools_full.exe";  Flags: waituntilterminated
Filename: "msiexec.exe"; Parameters: "/i ""{tmp}\mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-ssl-3.4.10-signed.msi"; WorkingDir: {tmp}; Flags: waituntilterminated
Filename: "msiexec.exe"; Parameters: "/i ""{tmp}\node-v6.11.0-x64.msi"; WorkingDir: {tmp}; Flags: waituntilterminated
Filename: "{tmp}\setup.bat";
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: shellexec postinstall skipifsilent
```

**Batch File**

```
cd C:/Users/%USERNAME%/Documents/myApp/api/
call npm install -g bower
call npm install -g grunt
call npm install -g grunt-cli
call npm config set msvs_version 2015 -global
call npm install bcrypt -save
call npm install
cd ../admin/
call npm install -g bower
call npm install -g grunt
call npm install -g grunt-cli
echo 1 | call gem install compass
call bower install
call npm install
```

Comment: I left out Filename: "{tmp}\python-3.5.4-amd64-webinstall.exe";  Flags: waituntilterminated
was also installed

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing the installer doesn't modify the PATH for you, so npm isn't being aliased as a command. If you invoke npm by using the absolute path to the executable, it should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks Squshman and posit labs, will give that a go

Comment: If the installer wasn't modifying the `PATH`, how would the batch file work after the installer completes?

Comment: Should it be modifying PATH? I don't think so. I wouldn't be super happy if an installer overwrote my node version without asking.